# Disable Dynamic Windows 8.1 Tile Colors

Tags: windows, gui, modern-ui, windows-8.1

Is there a registry setting to turn the dynamic tile color off?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No you can't turn off dynamic tile colours.

But you can create custom tile settings for each exe. Microsft describes this in [How to customize Start screen tiles for desktop apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn393983.aspx)

You basically create a *"exefilename".VisualElementsManifest.xml* with the following contents:

```
<Application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<VisualElements
    BackgroundColor="#606060"
    ShowNameOnSquare150x150Logo="on"
    ForegroundText="light" />
 </Application>
```

If you choose a bright backgroundcolour, change "light" to "dark"

To activate any changes you make, you have to **"edit" (basically update the timestamp) of the .lnk file** in the startmenu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Oblytile to alter icon, icon size and tile colour for anything.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1899865

Comment: Please include the details of the answer here instead of only providing the link.  If the link stops working, then this answer no longer helps.