# Windows 8.1 Coloured Tiles

Tags: windows-8.1, user-interface

Is it possible to turn of the new tile background colours in the Windows 8.1 Update?

I don't want to use a third party app but I'd be okay with modifying the registry if it can get rid of these terrible colours.

[image]

Comment: This is a good question. Any luck?

Comment: Duplicates: http://superuser.com/questions/661299/disable-dynamic-windows-8-1-tile-colors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a registry tweak for this, why not go for the third party tool ? things can get really easy if you consider ,

Stardock has recently released beta version of Decor8 to support windows 8.1, you can use this awesome tool to get rid of the custom colours of the tiles , [here is a link](http://www.programmerfish.com/customize-windows-8-1-start-screen-tiles-interface-using-decor8/#.Umedo1BpmGU) which gives a tutorial and download outlet

Or you can use [OblyTile for Windows 8.1](http://killeralqasmi.deviantart.com/art/WINDOWS-8-1-ULTIMATE-TILES-OblyTile-D-G-393635865) , [here is a tutorial](http://www.programmerfish.com/create-custom-tiles-for-applications-in-windows-8-using-oblytile/) on this tool , it lets you create your own tiles, with colours of your choice, icons, images etc

Comment: I guess my issue is that all the third party stuff I've seen are custom tiles. I just want the coloured feature turned off. I don't want to create new tiles. Also, I'd like the minimum amount of software on my computer necessary.